# calling function from linux executable file

Tags: python, c

I have python code like this:

```
import svmlight

training_data = __import__('data').train0
test_data = __import__('data').test0
model = svmlight.learn(training_data, type='classification', verbosity=0)
svmlight.write_model(model, 'my_model.dat')
predictions = svmlight.classify(model, test_data)
```

Now I have linux executable file `svmlight_classify`, for above code  and all function are also inside this executable. This executable was create from c code using make command.

can I directly call `classify()` function from `svmlight_classify` executable file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, I don't think that you can directly call functions in an executable, but you can call functions in a shared library. You seem to have access to the C source code, so you should be able to build a shared library like this:

```
$ gcc -c -fPIC -o svmlight_classify.o svmlight_classify.c
$ gcc -shared -Wl,-soname,libsvmlight_classify.so -o libsvmlight_classify.so  svmlight_classify.o
```

This should produce a shared library named `libsvmlight_classify.so`. Now you can load and call its functions using `ctypes`:

```
from ctypes import cdll

lib = cdll.LoadLibrary('./libsvmlight_classify.so')
lib.classify()
```

Probably it will be more complicated than the above. For example, there may be arguments that need to be passed to `lib.classify()` of a type more complicated than int, string etc. Without the function prototype we can't advise, but the above is generally what you need to do.

Answer (score 1):

You can call C functions from DLL using `ctypes` standard module.

```
import ctypes
dll = ctypes.CDLL('your.dll') # or 'your.exe'
python_int_returned = dll.YourFunc(ctypes.c_int(3)).value
```

ctypes.CDLL can also be created for executable (checked it right now). I didn't check it for calling functions. Anyway you need to declare C functions in C++ code with `extern "C"` statement, because C++ compiler adds some "underscored" prefixes and suffixes into a binary for C++ functions by default (`extern "C"` turns it off).

Complicated data is often transferred to C code as a memory pointer (`ctypes.POINTER` can be useful).

Comment: I guess ctype is for windows executable like dll or exe, but in my case, I have linux executable

Comment: It should work for Linux also. Example:
testlib = ctypes.CDLL('/full/path/to/testlib.so')

Comment: thanks again, I tried this `
dll = ctypes.CDLL('svm_classify')` which gives error `OSError: svm_classify: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`. The file is in same directory and also imported dll

Comment: Can you run it by subprocess.call('svm_classify') ? Full path?

Comment: yes, progress. But as `svm_classify` needs input parameters it gives error `Not enough input parameters!`

Comment: how to pass parameters in `subprocess.call('svm_classify')`

Comment: You can pass only string arguments to `subprocess.call` like `subprocess.call('svm_classify -p param1')` or `subprocess.call(['svm_classify', '-p', 'param1'])`. Second way is better for params with spaces.

Comment: it this correct way `dll = subprocess.call('/root/Desktop/blondel/svm_light/wcauchois-pysvmlight-d8f3bb76d016/examples/svm_classify',model,input1)`

Comment: But creation of ctypes.CDLL for linux executable is also interesting issue! Please let me know if you could do that. Did you try `sys.path.append(os.getcwd())` before ctypes.CDLL('svm_classify')?

Comment: Don't forget about square brackets, it's a Python list. `dll = subprocess.call(['/root/Desktop/blondel/svm_light/wcauchois-pysvmlight-d8f3bb76d0‌​16/examples/svm_classify',model,input1])` can probably be correct if model and input1 variables are strings (I don't know how svm_classify parses cmd params).

Comment: in `model` I am reading `feature/pair` value and in `input1` input text value. When I used last command you suggested, it gave `SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xe2' in file simple3.py on line 28, but no encoding declared; see http://www.python.org/peps/pep-0263.html for details
`